# Running a non-official android app on my Ubuntu pc without having an android phone

Tags: 16.04, android, android-emulator

I want to install an app which is unofficial and not on the play store. I have the .apk and I want to run it on my Ubuntu desktop.

All programs I've found so far either require a play store account and an android device, or just do one step in the process (e.g. running but not compiling).

Comment: You could install an Android_x86 virtual machine, e.g. using Qemu/KVM and install your APK in there.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome has Chrome app called **ARC WELDER** to run android apps inside the browser environment.(It is primarily for Chromebooks, which have only a browser, to run android apps, but works on Ubuntu as well)

Not every app works. But it might be worth a try.

STEPS:

- Install Arc Welder in Google Chrome from the Web Store https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn
- Launch the Arc Welder app. Add your apk and do the basic configuration of your app.
- Hit **Test** and hope that your app runs :p

Comment: Did your app run?  :p